# parse push notification acting peculiarly

Tags: ios, parse-platform, push-notification

After an all nighter with enough caffeine to kill a small rhino, I got parse push notifications working only to realize it does not act as expected.

The notifications are sent, and received but in didReceiveRemoteNotification are NOT ALWAYS acting as coded. Out of the 5 test notifications sent, 2 worked perfectly. The rest of the time the notification still appeared in notification center but do not interact with didReceiveRemoteNotification.

Since it did work a few times, I'm not sure what code to post since I'm assuming the code in appDelegate is fine. And the certificates/ plist/ provisional profile must also be set up correctly since the notification alert comes through all the time.

So I guess I'm wondering if there is any possible problems that would cause notifications to work differently.

```
         if application.applicationState != UIApplicationState.Background {
        // Track an app open here if we launch with a push, unless
        // "content_available" was used to trigger a background push (introduced in iOS 7).
        // In that case, we skip tracking here to avoid double counting the app-open.

        let preBackgroundPush = !application.respondsToSelector("backgroundRefreshStatus")
        let oldPushHandlerOnly = !self.respondsToSelector("application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:")
        var pushPayload = false
        if let options = launchOptions {
            pushPayload = options[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey] != nil

        }
        if (preBackgroundPush || oldPushHandlerOnly || pushPayload) {
            PFAnalytics.trackAppOpenedWithLaunchOptions(launchOptions)
        }
    }
```

Comment: The behaviour of remote notifications will vary depending on whether your app is in the foreground or the background and whether you specify content-available in the payload. What situations are you having problems with?

Comment: okay that is helpful to know, I would like my app to run the code in didReceiveRemoteNotification all the time so how would i specify this in the payload?

Comment: You should specify the content-available key in your push - https://devforums.apple.com/thread/209664?tstart=0

Comment: so this is my code that clearly says not to run didReceiveRemoteNotification if in background, could this be changed within this portion of code?

Answer (score 0):

The problem begins here:

```
let oldPushHandlerOnly = !self.respondsToSelector("application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:")
```

**Push notifications are handled by two different methods, depending on if your app is currently in the background or foreground.** This means you will need to have your code in two different methods. Trying to detect if one method is available isn't going to help.

Instead, you need to push push handler code in two places. As Ray Wenderlich points out in his [excellent introduction to push](http://www.raywenderlich.com/32963/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-2):

> **application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:** If your app wasn’t running when the notification came in, it is launched and the notification is passed as part of the launchOptions dictionary.
>
> **application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:** This method is invoked if your app is active when a notification comes in. On iOS 4.0 or later, if your app was suspended in the background it is woken up and this method is also called. You can use UIApplication’s applicationState property to find out whether your app was suspended or not.

Make sure you are handling pushes in both places.